# App submission ios7

Tags: ios7, appstore-approval

The following is mandatory: "Update the launch image to include the status bar area if it doesn’t already do so.". This might sound stupid but I don't exactly understand what this means. Do I actually need to but a static status bar into my launch image ? Or does it just mean I should be aware that the statusbar will be overlapped and should adjust my image if nessecary? So doing nothing will not get my app rejected? Any clarification on this subject is appreciated.

Comment: This is the first I hear of this..and I just submitted a new app yesterday...Will be keeping a look out on answers on what this is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This only means that your launch image must be full resolution of the device display:
Example: 
- iPad Mini Retina Display: 2048px x 1536px

Comment: So if my app passed a pre ios7 submission with the 3 launch images (2x for iPhone 4 and 1x for iPhone 5) i should be fine ?

Comment: If they are full-screen resolution, yes.